# Grails/GORM Class and subclass with composite key mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I need to map Domain classes and subclasses of a legacy database.

The model thath I need to recreate with Grails is to this tables:

[Tables structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8muZ.jpg)

CARD_PAYMET and CHEQUE_PAYMENT is subclasses of PAYMENT and share a composite key of two field: OrderId and PaymentId.

I try some ex scenarios, but I can´t arrive to solution. None of then recreate the same model data, and I can´t change this model.

Can any one help me?

Thanks.

Comment: How is inheritance modeled in the legacy database?

Comment: Your question is unclear at some point. Please re read your question and add the domain class code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your database looks like a good fit for [table-per-subclass inheritance](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-inheritance/). First, since you're using a composite primary key, your domain classes need to implement the `Serializable` interface. Then it's a matter of mapping each table column to a property.

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes=['orderId', 'paymentId'])
class Payment implements Serializable {
    int orderId
    int paymentId
    float amount

    static mapping = { 
        version false
        tablePerHierarchy false
        id composite: ['orderId', 'paymentId']
        orderId column: 'OrderId'
        paymentId column: 'PaymentId'
        /* Assuming case-insensitive db, so I left out 'Amount'. */
    }   
}

class CardPayment extends Payment {
    String cardType

    static mapping = {
        version false
        cardType column: 'CardType'
    }
}

class ChequePayment extends Payment {
    int checkNumber

    static mapping = {
        version false
        checkNumber column: 'CheckNumber'
    }
}
```

*Note: In this example I used Groovy's `EqualsAndHashCode` AST transformation to implement `Serializable`.*

With the domain classes in place you'll be able to do GORM polymorphic queries:

```
def payments = Payment.list() // All Payments (Payment, CardPayment, and ChequePayment).
def cardPayments = CardPayment.list() // Only CardPayments.
...
def nicePayments = Payment.where { amount > 1000 }.list()
```

Comment: Emmanuel: I already try this scenario and I have an exception when I try to launch the application: subclass key mapping has wrong number of columns when Grails try to deploy any of subclass of Payment

Comment: Additionally, here`s the stack trace error: Caused by MappingException: subclass key mapping has wrong number of columns: pagos.CardPayment type: component[orderId,paymentId]

Comment: I did some experimentation and concluded that *table-per-subclass* inheritance does not support composite primary keys :( It is possible to create domain classes for the tables, but only without inheritance. I created a demo using a Groovy trait. It works... OK. Obviously you don't get polymorphic queries and you have to manage the referential integrity manually. Check it out here: https://bitbucket.org/erosa/inheritance-example/overview.